# Triplets of distinct integers > 1 that return integer values.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, functions, diophantine-equations

If $(A, B, C)$ are distinct integers $> 1$, and $$f(A, B, C) = \frac{\frac{A^2-1}{A} + \frac{B^2-1}{B}}{\frac{C^2-1}{C}},$$ then for what (if any) triplets $(A, B, C)$ is $f(A, B, C)$ an integer?

UPDATE: I've done some more work and have come up with the following: Based on the equations I combined to arrive at $f(A,B,C)$, it follows that: $$f(A,B,C)>2\Rightarrow A>B>C>1$$ and $$f(A,B,C)=2\Rightarrow A>C>B>1$$

My further work:

Let $f(A,B,C)=k$ where $k>1$ is an integer. Rewrite $f(A,B,C)$ as $$k=\frac{A-\frac{1}{A}+B-\frac{1}{B}}{C-\frac{1}{C}}$$

Thus $$A-\frac{1}{A}+B-\frac{1}{B}-k(C-\frac{1}{C})=A-\frac{1}{A}+B-\frac{1}{B}-kC+\frac{k}{C}=0$$

Note that $\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}<1$ for all integer $A,B$ such that $A>B>1$.

Now we consider three cases: $1)$ $k<C$, $2)$ $k=C$, $3)$ $k>C$.

Case $1$: $k<C$

Since $\frac{k}{C}<1$ it follows that these equations hold:$$A+B=kC$$ $$\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}=\frac{A+B}{AB}=\frac{k}{C}$$

By substitution $$\frac{kC}{AB}=\frac{k}{C}\Rightarrow AB=C^2$$

This is only true if $A=np^2$, $B=nq^2$, and $C=npq$ for integers $n,p,q\geq 1$ and $p>q$. From this we have $$p^2>pq; pq>q^2\Rightarrow p^2>pq>q^2\Rightarrow np^2>npq>nq^2\Rightarrow A>C>B>1\Rightarrow k\leq2$$ This last condition, $k\leq2$, follows from the conditions stated above and leaves us with two possibilities: $k=2$ or $k=1$.

If $k=1$ we have $A+B=C$ which violates the condition $A>C$.

If $k=2$ we have $A+B=2C\Rightarrow \frac{A+B}{2}=C$. By substitution we have $$\frac{A+B}{AB}=\frac{2}{\frac{A+B}{2}}$$ $$4AB=(A+B)^2\Rightarrow A^2-2AB+B^2=0\Rightarrow (A-B)^2=0$$

However, this leads to the result that $A=B$ which violates that stated conditions.

Case $1$, $k<C$, fails.

Case $2$: $k=C$

Since $\frac{k}{C}=1$ it follows that $$A+B+1=C^2$$ $$\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}=0$$

This later equation is clearly false and thus Case $2$, $k=C$ fails.

Case $3$: $k>C$

Let $p,q$ be integers with $C>q\geq0$ and $p>1$. From this we can write $k$ as $k=pC+q$.

Note that $q=0 \Rightarrow A+B+p=C^2$ and $\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}=0$ (as above) which is clearly a contradiction, so $q\geq1$.

Substituting in $k$ above we have $$A-\frac{1}{A}+B-\frac{1}{B}-pC^2-qC+p+\frac{q}{C}=0$$

Applying the same logic as above we have the following equations $$\frac{A+B}{AB}=\frac{q}{C}$$ $$A+B=pC^2+qC-p$$

By substitution we have the following system of equations (one cubic and one quadratic) $$pC^3+qC^2-pC=qAB\Rightarrow pC^3+qC^2-pC-qAB=0$$ $$pC^2+qC-p-A-B=0$$

Since at least one $C$ that works must solve both equations we denote the roots of the cubic as $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and the roots of the quadratic as $x_1,y_2$.

By Vieta's formulas we have $$x_1+x_2+x_3=-\frac{q}{p}$$ $$x_1 x_2+x_1 x_3+x_2 x_3=-1$$ $$x_1 x_2 x_3=\frac{qAB}{p}$$

and $$x_1+y_2=-\frac{q}{p}$$ $$x_1 y_2= -\frac{p+A+B}{p}$$

From the first equations (setting $x_1+x_2+x_3=x_1+y_2$) we have $y_2=x_2+x_3$.

Thus $$x_1 y_2=x_1 x_2+x_1 x_3=-\frac{p+A+B}{p}\Rightarrow x_2 x_3-\frac{p+A+B}{p}=-1\Rightarrow x_2 x_3=\frac{A+B}{p}$$ $$x_2 x_3=\frac{A+B}{p}\Rightarrow x_1\frac{A+B}{p}=\frac{qAB}{p}\Rightarrow x_1=\frac{qAB}{A+B}$$

Since $x_1=C$ and $B>C$ we have $$B>\frac{qAB}{A+B}\Rightarrow B^2>(q-1)AB$$

Since $A>B$ it follows $AB>B^2$ and so $q-1<1\Rightarrow q<2$. Since $q\neq0$ (see above) we have $q=1$ and so $C=\frac{AB}{A+B}$.

Substituting for $C$ in the quadratic (although the cubic has the same result) we have $$0=p(\frac{AB}{A+B})^2+\frac{AB}{A+B}-p-A-B$$ Which, after a fair bit of rearranging, becomes $$p=\frac{(A+B)^3-AB(A+B)}{(AB)^2-(A+B)^2}$$ Thus $f(A,B,C)$ is an integer (with $A,B,C$ constrained as above) iff $$p=\frac{(A+B)^3-AB(A+B)}{(AB)^2-(A+B)^2}$$ has integer solutions $p>0$ and $A>B>2$.

Any help with solving this last bit would be greatly appreciated. So far guesswork and Wolfram Alpha have failed to produce results.

Comment: What's the source of this question, please?

Comment: It does not have any source that I am aware of. I arrived at this expression while examining some properties of Pythagorean triples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(A,B,C)$ has no integral solutions for distinct integers $A,B,C$.

Let $f(A,B,C)=k$ as in the question. $k<C$ and $k=C$ have been shown above to lead to contradictions. $k>C$ has been shown to reduce to solving $$p=\frac{(A+B)^3-AB(A+B)}{(AB)^2-(A+B)^2}$$ $$C=\frac{AB}{A+B}$$ for positive integers as restricted above.

Start with: $$C=\frac{AB}{A+B}$$ This equation is identical to $$\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}=\frac{1}{C}$$ Let $A=C+s$ and $B=C+t$ with $s,t$ positive integers with $s>t$. We now have  $$\frac{1}{C+s}+\frac{1}{C+t}=\frac{1}{C} \Rightarrow (C+s)(C+t)=C(C+s+C+t)$$ $$C^2+C(s+t)+st=2C^2+C(s+t)\Rightarrow C^2=st$$

The solution set for this last equation is $s=na^2, t=nb^2, C=nab$ for positive integral $n,a,b; a>b$. From this we have $A=na^2+nab$ and $B=nb^2+nab$. Substituting into our equation for $p$ we have: $$p=\frac{(na^2+2nab+nb^2)^3-(na^2+nab)(nb^2+nab)(na^2+2nab+nb^2)}{((na^2+nab)(nb^2+nab))^2-(na^2+2nab+nb^2)^2}\Rightarrow$$

$$p=\frac{(n(a+b)^2)^3-n^2ab(a+b)^2(n(a+b)^2)}{(n^2ab(a+b)^2)^2-(n(a+b)^2)^2}\Rightarrow$$

$$p=\frac{n^3(a+b)^6-n^3ab(a+b)^4}{n^4a^2b^2(a+b)^4-n^2(a+b)^4}\Rightarrow$$

$$p=\frac{n(a+b)^2-nab}{n^2a^2b^2-1}=\frac{na^2+nab+nb^2}{n^2a^2b^2-1}\Rightarrow$$

$$p=\frac{na^2}{n^2a^2b^2-1}+\frac{nab}{n^2a^2b^2-1}+\frac{nb^2}{n^2a^2b^2-1}\Rightarrow$$

$$p\approx\frac{1}{nb^2}+\frac{1}{nab}+\frac{1}{na^2}<1|a,b,n\geq2$$

Thus $n,a,b$ must be small. In fact, a quick computer search reveals that $p=\frac{na^2+nab+nb^2}{n^2a^2b^2-1}$ is only greater than $1$ if $n=b=1$. Rewriting for $p$ we have $$p=\frac{a^2+a+1}{a^2-1}$$ which is clearly asymptotic to $1$.

Testing a few values, if $a=2$ then $p=2.\overline{3}$, if $a=3$ then $p=1.625$.

Since as $a$ gets larger $p$ gets smaller, and $p$ is asymptotic to $1$, clearly no integer $a\geq2$ results in an integral $p$.

Since there exist no integral $p$'s that can solve $k=pC+q$ (see the question for how to derive this expression) clearly $k$ is not greater than $C$ and Case $3$, $k>C$ fails.

$k=f(A,B,C)$ is neither less than, greater than, nor equal to $C$, which is clearly a contradiction and so,

$f(A,B,C)$ has no integral solutions for distinct integers $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 0):

We can  write $f(A,B,C)=\frac {(A^2-1)BC+(B^2-1)AC}{AB(C^2-1)}$ then $f(A,B,C)$ is an integer if $AB(C^2-1)|C((A^2-1)B+(B^2-1)A)$ $\Rightarrow$ because $GCD(C,C^2-1)=1$ then  $A|C \ or\ B|C$ and $ (C^2-1)|(A^2-1)B+(B^2-1)A $.

Comment: Does this answer claim that it's an integer *if and only if* one of $A,B,AB$ us a divisor of $C$? [not clear whether you're claiming an if and only if in the answer]

Comment: The factored form of $f(a,b,c)$ \has numerator $(a+b)(ab-1)c$ and denominator as you say $ab(c^2-1).$ So from $\gcd(c,c^2-1)=1$ we *do* have the necessary condition $(c^2-1)|(a+b)(ab-1).$ But I think for $ab$ we get from $\gcd(ab,ab-1)=1$ that another necessary condition is $ab|(a+b)c.$ That is, I don't think that the simple $ab|c$ follows, at least directly.

Comment: From $ab|(a+b)c$ it follows that for $ab$ to not divide $c$, $ab$ must divide $a+b$ and thus $ab\leq(a+b)$ which is equivalent to stating $a\leq\frac{b}{b-1}$. Since $a,b>1$ the only possible choice is $a=b=2$ since $b>2 \Rightarrow \frac{b}{b-1}<2$. However this violates the condition $a\neq b\neq c$. So $ab$ is not a divisor of $a+b$. This leaves two options: The above mentioned $ab|c$ or $a|(a+b)$ and $b|c$ which implies $a|b$ and thus $a|b|c$. (Note that a and b could be reversed but since both appear in the numerator of the expression above we can assume WLoG that $a<b$.)

Comment: @Ari No, the gcd of $ab$ and $a+b$ is not necessarily $1$. For example $a=2,b=6$ then $\gcd(ab,a+b)=\gcd(12,8)=4.$ So with $c=3$ in this case, $ab=12$ divides $(a+b)c=8 \cdot 3$, AND $ab$ fails to divide $c$, but yet $ab=12$ does not divide $a+b=8$ either.

Comment: @coffeemath Even if $ab$ and $a+b$ share a factor, that factor cannot be $ab$ if $a$ and $b$ fit the given constraints.

Comment: @Ari My view is that we certainly do have that $ab|(a+b)c$ if the expression is an integer. It may be that $ab$ has some of its factors used in $a+b$ and the rest used in $c$. That's what to me makes it difficult to get to a simple breakdown into cases. In other words I don't think there are two cases, one in which $ab|a+b$ and the other in which $ab|c.$ Since as you say $ab$ cannot completely divide $a+b$ it must partly divide $c$, and things get involved at that point.